# React-native Ios blank screen on first launch iPad running iOS 12.0.1

Tags: ios, react-native

React-native iOS blank screen on first launch iPad running iOS 12.0.1.
After closing the app and re-launching it, it displays normally.
This only happens on physical device, I couldn't reproduce it on Xcode simulators (it runs correctly).

This is the app in action: https://photos.app.goo.gl/ecwwuYGkh5QRHzU17

Libraries in use

```
{
    "name": "flightech",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest",
        "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/flightech/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "native-base": "^2.7.1",
        "react": "16.4.1",
        "react-native": "0.56.0",
        "react-native-background-fetch": "^2.4.3",
        "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",
        "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
        "react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.6",
        "react-native-push-notification": "^3.0.2",
        "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.31",
        "react-native-tab-view": "^1.0.2",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "23.4.0",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
        "jest": "23.4.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

Comment: did you solve this? I'm getting the same error when Apple reviews my app